# How to open excel file in one drive for business in browser using graph api

Tags: office365, onedrive, microsoft-graph-api

I am creating excel file on one drive for business using Microsoft graph API. after creating the excel file i need to open that file in browser. Microsoft graph api doesnt give any link to open the item/file in excel online. so to workaround this, when i get the response as shown below after excel file is created,

[image]

i create the path as shown below using the webUrl property from the response, and then this file can be open in excel online using window.open javascript method.

```
                                if (searchFileInfo.file) {
                                var index1 = searchFileInfo.eTag.indexOf('{'), index2 = searchFileInfo.eTag.indexOf('}');;
                                etag = searchFileInfo.eTag.substr(index1, index2);
                                var filePath = searchFileInfo.webUrl.substr(0, searchFileInfo.webUrl.indexOf('/Documents/InfoClientAddIn/' + excelFile()));
                                filePath = filePath + "/_layouts/15/WopiFrame.aspx?sourcedoc=" + etag + "&file=" + excelFile() + "&action=default";
                                defer.resolve(filePath);
                            } else {
                                defer.reject();
                            }
```

**Is this a correct approach to open excel in excel online if i am using Microsoft graph API. whats the correct approach**

Comment: I think this is the right approach if you are trying to open Excel Online in the browser UI. Microsoft Graph is a REST API so it doesn't really interact with Excel UI.

Comment: actually if i use one drive rest api instead of graph api, response used to have a property which would give me this path. and i could open the excel sheet without needing to do this string manipulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a temporary condition that the webUrl is returning the file download rather than the actual web experience for OneDrive for Business files.
We expect to address that in a later release, so you should not rely on the current URL format that is being returned.  In general, it's always dangerous to do path math on any absolute URLs returned from APIs.

If you want to protect your code somewhat in the interim, it is very likely that once this issue is fixed the webUrl will have query parameters added to it, but unfortunately that's not a 100% guarantee that other things than the fix won't also cause query parameters to appear.

Comment: do you see any issue in the way i am constructing url to open in excel sheet. is there any other best solution, right now

Comment: Hi Shyam, We are using the file ID in the path instead of the webURL you have in your URL.

Answer (score 1):

> Microsoft graph api doesnt give any link to open the item/file in excel online

I think it does. 
Using [createLink](http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/item_createlink), for example with the POST parameters: {"type": "view", "scope": "anonymous"}, you get a response like:

```
{
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#permission",
"@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.permission",
"id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"roles": [
    "read"
],
"link": {
    "scope": "anonymous",
    "type": "view",
    "webUrl": "https://stuff-ponting-to-your-company/_layouts/15/guestaccess.aspx?guestaccesstoken=xxxxxxxxxx%3d&docid=xxxxxxxxx&rev=1"
}
}
```

The **webUrl** opens the item in office online, in read-only, or read-write mode, depending on the POST request parameters.